# Error in arima model for time series model of R

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am trying to create a time series model using auto.arima and xreg function in R. I am getting the following error(highlighted in yellow):
[image]

Please provide help in debugging this error!

Comment: You have to provide the forecasted values for the independent variables/xreg as well.

Comment: Hi @AlexB, if you can provide the syntax for that,that would be helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ARIMA forecasting with auto.Arima() and xreg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249477/arima-forecasting-with-auto-arima-and-xreg)